# How do I wire this PIR motion sensor?

Tags: hardware, wiring, motion

<sup>[Apologies if this is off-topic; I'm not sure where else to ask.](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/446/10113)</sup>

I've tried working through [Adafruit's lovely tutorial](http://learn.adafruit.com/adafruits-raspberry-pi-lesson-12-sensing-movement/), but it appears that the component I'm working with ([EKMC1603112](http://pewa.panasonic.com/assets/pcsd/catalog/papirs-ekmc-catalog.pdf)) is not set up the same way as Adafruit's.  (I had no idea there could be such variance.)

I currently have the PIR signal (`OUT` on page 5 of the datasheet) wired to GPIO1 (BCM 18) on the Pi and VDD (5V) and GND wired to their respective pins.
(I can take a picture if necessary, but there is another component wired up that will make the circuit slightly confusing.)

I'm using the following code, modeled after the Adafruit tutorial, assuming red is VDD, black is GND, and yellow is signal.

```
import RPi.GPIO as io
import time
io.setmode(BCM)
io.setup(18, io.IN)
while True:
  io.input(18)
  time.sleep(1)
```

When I run this code, `RPi.GPIO.input` is returning True regardless of whether or not motion is (supposedly) being detected.
What am I doing wrong?

---

I have it set up exactly as Adafruit does, less the component wired from BCM23 to GND.

[image: wiring]

Comment: Is it feasible that the component is DOA?

Comment: Very nice formatting, with a picture to sport!

Comment: @syb0rg XD Thanks?  [I've had a bit of practice](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/17423) ;)  Just thought I'd branch out and try something <del>useful</del>new.

Comment: I'm not sure if you've noticed, but I've been going through a lot of posts lately and editing them to improve their format. It's nice to have a little break with this one.

Comment: @syb0rg Ha! I know the feeling. Sometimes I wonder if newcomers realize SE uses markdown.